# qmake platform scopes

Tags: operating-system, qmake

A standard c++ qmake-based library is developed for Win32, Mac, and Linux. In the qmake project file, the platform-dependent sources are included like this:

```
win32 {
     SOURCES += WinSystem.cpp
     HEADERS += WinSystem.h
 }

macx {
     SOURCES += MacSystem.cpp
     HEADERS += MacSystem.h
}

unix {
     SOURCES += LinuxSystem.cpp
     HEADERS += LinuxSystem.h
}
```

Now on OS X both `unix` and `macx` are defined, so the Linux files are also included and cause error! What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can negate and combine blocks, so in unix but not in mac would be:

```
unix:!macx {
  SOURCES += LinuxSystem.cpp
  HEADERS += LinuxSystem.h
}
```