# How to specify Linux Architecture in a Qt project(.pro) file?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to build a MultiArch Application for Ubuntu. I have to compile it separately on different Architectures. However I have to do a lot of manual changes Each time the Architecture changes. For Instance-

> #linux-g++:LIBS += $$DESTDIR/lib32/libusb-1.0.so      #arch-specific changes
>
> linux-g++:LIBS += $$DESTDIR/lib64/libusb-1.0.so

Here I have to comment and uncomment a line every time I'm compiling for a different Architecture. I have to do this on a number of places.

However if there is a way to specify the Linux Architecture in the .pro file itself then my task will become much easier. I know that we can use **win32** and **macx** scope variables and **linux-g++** for Ubuntu. But I want to distinguish between **ubuntu 32 bit** and **64 bit** Architectures. Is there any way this might be achieved a little more elegently?

I have already seen
[qmake platform scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371363/qmake-platform-scopes)
and I just want to specify that I'm looking to distinguish between **linux32bit** and **linux64bit** .

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356666/identifier-for-win64-configuration-in-qmake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED IT:

```
linux-g++{
   !contains(QT_ARCH, x86_64){
       LIB=lib32
       message("Compiling for 32bit system")
    } else {
       LIB=lib64
       message("Compiling for 64bit system")
   }
}
```