# Add conditional macro depending on Qt version

Tags: c++, qt

One can compile different code depending on the current Qt version:

```
#if QT_VERSION < 0x050000
.....
#else
.....
#endif
```

However, Qt4 and Qt5 have different macros for checking the operating system: `Q_WS_WIN -> Q_OS_WIN` and `Q_WS_X11 -> Q_OS_LINUX`, respectively. How to add `#ifdef` macro for certain operating system?

Comment: `#if defined Q_WS_X11 || defined Q_OS_LINUX`

Comment: That or just define your own variable in your `pro` file where you also branch your configuration based on the operating system ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6371554/1559401)) and can than call the variable inside your own header/source file.

Comment: Note that `#if QT_VERSION < 0x050000` is a problem unless you remember to use hex for the sub-components.  For example, to check for a version less that 5.10, you must do `#if QT_VERSION < 0x050A00`, *not* `#if QT_VERSION < 0x051000`.  Less error-prone, for those who don't automatically think in hexadecimal, is to do `#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 10, 0))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `QT_VERSION`, you can check both versions like this:

```
#if defined(Q_WS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_WIN)
// Windows...
#elif defined(Q_WS_X11) || defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
// Linux...
#endif
```